# Checking if number exists or not in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, postman

```
registerRouter.route('/uidcheck')
.post((req, res, next) => {
  Register.find({ aadhaar: Register.aadhaar })
  .then((user) => {
    res.statusCode=200;
    res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
    res.json('User already exists');
  }, (err) => next(err))
  .catch((err) => next(err));
})
```

I have been trying to check whether entered aadhaar number exists in the database(mongodb) or not. I made the code like above, which is returning me always "users already exists" even though the aadhaar number I posted (through postman) does not exists. Atleast it should return any error(no need to create any).

I have even used findOne() query, but no use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the code needs to be changed like this :-

```
router.post('/uidcheck', async(req, res) => {
    try {
        const exists = await Register.findOne({ aadhaar : req.body.aadhaar})
        if(exists == null){
            res.statusCode = 200;
            res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
            res.json({success: true, status: 'You are allowed to register'});
        }else{
            res.statusCode=200;
            res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
            res.json({status: 'User already exists'});
        }
    }
    catch(error){
        res.status(500).send({message: "Error checking"});
    }
})
```

I made a few corrections, it **worked**!

Answer (score 0):

You will go to the catch block only if there is an `error`. An error is like a network error.

Asking the DB to find a user and it not finding one is **not** an error, i.e. you code will still go to the `.then` block. It is in this `.then` block you should check

```
.then( (user) => {
  if (user) {
    // all ok
  } else {
    // there is no user
  }
}
```

and write your business logic.

Comment: I have changed as you said, but no use. I think there should change in `.find()` query. Can you suggest other way.